# Sqlite thinks I lack bindings

Tags: python, sqlite

In lack of any source on how to create an `sqlite` query in Python from a dictionary, I built my own:

```
    updates = ', '.join(["`"+field+"`" + '=:'+field for field in information.keys() if field != 'name'])
    where = ' WHERE name == :name'
    values = {':'+field: value for field, value in information.items()}

    query = 'UPDATE firms SET ' + updates + where
    c.execute(query, values)
```

However, I get

```
sqlite3.ProgrammingError: You did not supply a value for binding 1.
```

This befuddles me, as I think I have supplied all I should have:

```
In[374]: query
Out[374]: 'UPDATE firms SET `founded`=:founded, `size`=:size, `headquarters`=:headquarters, `type`=:type, `revenue`=:revenue WHERE name == :name'
In[375]: information
Out[375]: 
{'founded': '1962',
 'headquarters': 'Bentonville, AR',
 'name': 'Walmart',
 'revenue': '$10+ billion (USD) per year',
 'size': '10000+ employees',
 'type': 'Company - Public (WMT)'}
```

Comment: Shouldn't those backticks be double quotes?

Comment: @holdenweb I'm not that familiar with sqlite, but as I recall from elsewhere, backticks were used to fields, and double quotes to indicate string values

Comment: Well I do know that strings are delimited by single quotes in all known versions of SQL. In all those I'm familiar with, field names (when quoted) require double quotes. Maybe that's the error. In the query, you don't need quotes about the column names because they are all valid SQL identifiers

Comment: Aside: the `updates` assignment might be more readable as: `updates = ', '.join("\`{0}\`=:{0}".format(field) for field in information if field != 'name')`

Comment: Quoting rules are expressed here: https://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html  Backticks are non-standard, but are included for MySql compatability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the `:` in the `values` keys. Try this:

```
values = {field: value for field, value in information.items()}
```

Or, more succintly:

```
values = information
```

Sample program:

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect(":memory:")
c = conn.cursor()

c.execute("create table firms (founded, hq, name, rev, size, type)")
c.execute("insert into firms ( name ) values (?) ",("bar", ))
conn.commit()

def update(information):
    updates = ', '.join(["`"+field+"`" + '=:'+field for field in information.keys() if field != 'name'])
    where = ' WHERE name == :name'
    values = information
    query = 'UPDATE firms SET ' + updates + where
    c.execute(query, values)
    conn.commit()

update(dict(name='bar', founded='1062', rev='1 MILLION DOLLARS!'))
print c.execute('select * from firms').fetchall()
```

Result:

```
[(u'1062', None, u'bar', u'1 MILLION DOLLARS!', None, None)]
```